# MVC 5 Select list - user input

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, select, combobox

I am using the following to generate a dropdownlist of provinces based on the country selection:

```
  <select id="Province" name="Province"  class="form-control  input-sm">
    @{ 
       string[] provinces = ViewBag.ProvincesForSelectedCountry;
       string selectedProvinceName = null;
     }
    @{
       if (Model != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Province))
       {
          selectedProvinceName = Model.Province;
       } 
       else 
       {
          selectedProvinceName = ConfigData.DefaultProvinceName;
       }
     }
    @foreach (var anEntry in provinces)
    {
       string selectedTextMark = anEntry == selectedProvinceName 
          ? "selected=\"selected\"" 
          : String.Empty;
       <option value="@(anEntry)" @(selectedTextMark)>@(anEntry)</option>
    }
  </select>
```

The challenge is I don't have a list of provinces (states) for other countries! Is there a way to allow for the user to type in the name of the province? Like a combobox.

Comment: Why in the world are you not using the `DropDownListFor()` method t generate your `<select>`? Since you have no `ID` for your Provinces, you could consider using a jquery autocomplete control, or include an 'Add' button that pops up a dialog for adding a new Province that then gets added to you dropdownlist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do it using Knockout-Kendo combobox, here is the solution:
Controller:

```
   public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.CountryID = new SelectList(db.Countries, "ID", "Name", "34");
.....

   public JsonResult GetState(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {   id = 34;  }
            var data =   db.States.Where(x => x.CountryID == id)
                    .Select( x =>
                            new
                            {
                                ID = x.ID,
                                Name = x.Name
                            }).ToList();
            return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

In the View:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Country", ViewBag.CountryID as SelectList, "Select...",
 new { onchange = "UpdateProvinces();" })
<input data-bind="kendoComboBox: { dataTextField: 'Name', dataValueField: 'ID',
 data: choices, value: selectedChoice }" />
```

Here is the JavaScript:

```
function UpdateProvinces() {
        var countryId = $("#Country  option:selected").val();
        $.getJSON("/Home/GetState/" + countryId,
            null,
            function (data) {
                objVM.choices(data);
            });
    }
    function ItemViewModel(arg) {
        arg = 34;
        var self = this;
        this.choices = ko.observableArray([]),
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: '@Url.Action("GetState", "Home")',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: { id: arg },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    self.choices(data);
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    alert(err.status + " : " + err.statusText);
                }
            });
        var selectedChoice = {
            ID: self.ID,
            Name: self.Name
        };
        self.selectedChoice = ko.observable();
    }
    var objVM = new ItemViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(objVM);
```

**Edit:**

Another alternative is to use Telerik MVC UI Combobox http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/combobox/cascadingcombobox